# Does Phoebe believe that gravity exists?

Tags: friends, continuity

When Phoebe is trying to get pregnant, she lies upside down in a chair and says "I'll let gravity do its job". However, seasons later, she tells Ross she doesn't believe that gravity exists.

Is this just a simple continuity error, a hidden joke, or just Phoebe being Phoebe?

Comment: It’s possible for someone to believe something and then abandon that belief.

Comment: It could be simply, a generally speaking....

Comment: @ruffdove, in a general case and in real life, yes, but we are talking about Pheobe, and in this case, I would say it's very unlikely.

Comment: Seems to me not believing in gravity could be a call back to the earlier episode when gravity did not “do its job”.  (Or did she get pregnant? I have seen only a few episodes.)

Answer (score 6):

Phoebe is the Queen of Mean.  She really believes in both gravity and evolution, she's just playing a nasty trick on Ross. See, after Ross admits the possibility that he's wrong, she says "that was fun."

Comment: This is plausible.

Comment: I don't think she saying "That was fun" has any weight on the theory that Phoebe actually believes in gravity

Comment: @Vishwa What is problematic is that the body of this question is not consistent with the title.  Whether Phoebe actually believes in gravity is irrelevant to the scene.  The essence of the scene is that she gets a scientist to abandon his core beliefs.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger The scientist in this case (Ross) **did not** abandon his beliefs, he just lost (not 100% lost, but didnt win), his attempt to show Phoebe about the gravity.

Comment: @Vishwa this is semantics.  A true scientist would not waver. Phoebe got him to cave.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I'm not sure Ross did. he just gave up "trying to teach Phoebe". Can't consider that as caving.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that Phoebe only kidding. She says one Day this and the next Day the opposite.  But generally she´s believing in gravity. Think about the Episode, where she think, that the Spirit of her dead Mother lives in the Cat.